# Substituting the inheritance in a decorator pattern with interfaces

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, decorator

I'm designing a class with multiple decorators - thereby relying on inheritance relationships.
Since multiple inheritance isn't allowed in Java, I try to figure out a way to substitute all inheritance relationships [extends] with interfaces [implements].

I tried several approaches but none of them worked out. Especially my approach of multiple decorations with the same decorator is not working in my interface-conversions:

```
Computer computer = new Computer();

computer = new Loudspeaker(new Loudspeaker(computer));
System.out.println("My system with " + computer.buy() );
```

The hole approach of this pattern is designed around decorating with **two** loudspeakers.

This results in the printout:
*My system with a computer and a loudspeaker and a loudspeaker*

Do you have any suggestion for getting rid of as much inheritance as possible? My hole code:

```
protected class Computer {

protected String buy() {
    return "a computer";
} }


public class Loudspeaker extends Decorator {

Computer computer;

public Loudspeaker(Computer c) {
    computer = c;
}

@Override
public String buy() {
    return computer.buy() + " and a loudspeaker";
}}


public abstract class Decorator extends Computer {
    protected abstract String buy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple aspects that you need to think. First of which is the model for a computer sale. But just for your example something like below helps as start. There is more optimising possible ...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CompositionEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Computer computer = new Computer(100.00);
        LoudSpeaker loudSpeaker = new LoudSpeaker(20.50);
        computer.addPeripheral(loudSpeaker);
        computer.addPeripheral(loudSpeaker);
        System.out.println(computer.getPrice());
    }
}

class Computer implements Sellable {
    private final List<Peripheral> peripherals = new ArrayList<>();
    private final double basePrice;

    public Computer(double basePrice) {
        this.basePrice = basePrice;
    }

    boolean addPeripheral(Peripheral device) {
        return peripherals.add(device);
    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return basePrice + peripherals.stream().mapToDouble(Sellable::getPrice).sum();
    }
}

class LoudSpeaker implements Peripheral {
    private double price;

    public LoudSpeaker(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}

interface Peripheral extends Sellable {
}

interface Sellable {
    double getPrice();
}
```

Comment: A resonable approach. Thank you for your suggestion. I still have to figure out, if it has similar capabilities like a decorator pattern, e. g. decorating a class where only the bytecode but not the sourcecode is available.